# CURL proxy problems

Tags: php, curl, proxy

I have a problem with this code:

```
<html>
<head><title>Son_Of_Diablo's Hit Booster</title>

<script language="JavaScript">
    function onlyNumbers(evt)
    {
    var e = event || evt;
    var charCode = e.which || e.keyCode;

    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
        return false;

    return true;

    }
</script></head>

<body bgcolor="black">
<style type="text/css">
body,td,th {
    color: #00CC00;
}
</style>

<div align=center>
<h1>Son_Of_Diablo's Hit Booster</h1><br />
<form action="" method ="post">
    Site to boost: <br /><input type="text" name="url" style="border:3px double #00CC00;background-color:#000000;color:#00CC00;" /><br /><br />
    Proxy to use: <br /><textarea rows="5" cols="16" type="text" name="proxy" style="border:3px double #00CC00;background-color:#000000;color:#00CC00;" /></textarea><br /><br />
    User Agent to use: <br /><input type="text" name="agent"  style="border:3px double #00CC00;background-color:#000000;color:#00CC00;" /><br /><br />
    Referer from:<br /> <input type="text" name="ref" style="border:3px double #00CC00;background-color:#000000;color:#00CC00;" /><br  /><br />
    How many hits: <br /><input type="text" name="num" onkeypress="return onlyNumbers();" value="1" style="border:3px double #00CC00;background-color:#000000;color:#00CC00;" /><br /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="BOOST" style="border:3px double #00CC00;background-color:#000000;color:#00CC00;" />
</form>
</div>

<?php

function upordown($url, $proxy, $agent, $ref){
    $agents =  array("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1309.0 Safari/537.17", "Mozilla/6.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:16.0.1) Gecko/20121011 Firefox/16.0.1", "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.6; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0; InfoPath.2; SLCC1; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 2.0.50727) 3gpp-gba UNTRUSTED/1.0", "Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 6_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10A5355d Safari/8536.25", "Opera/12.80 (Windows NT 5.1; U; en) Presto/2.10.289 Version/12.02");
    $agentsL = count($agents);
    $max = $agentsL;
    $cs = curl_init($url);
    $agentt = rand(0, 5);

    curl_setopt($cs, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
    //curl_setopt($cs, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($cs, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
    curl_setopt($cs, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
    curl_setopt($cs, CURLOPT_REFERER, $ref);
    curl_exec($cs);

    sleep(10);
    curl_close ($cs);
}

if (isset($_POST['url']) == true && empty($_POST['url']) == false){
        $count = 0;
        $num = $_POST['num'];
        $proxy = $_POST['proxy'];
        $proxyE = explode("\n", $proxy);
        $proxyL = count($proxyE);

        while ($count < $num){
        //if($count != $proxyL && $count < $proxyL){
        $url = trim($_POST['url']);
        $agent = $_POST['agent'];
        $agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1309.0 Safari/537.17";
        $ref = $_POST['ref'];
        foreach($proxyE as $proxys){
        if(filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) == true){
            if(upordown($url, $proxys, $agent, $ref) == true){

            }else{
                echo 'Failed to add a hit from <strong>'.$proxys.'</strong><br />';
            }
        }else{
            echo 'Invalid URL';
        }
        $count++;
        /*}else{
        echo "<strong>ERROR:</strong> Not enought proxies!";
        }*/}}
}

?>

<br /><br />
<hr />
<br />
</body>
</html>
```

It's really messy I know..

So my problem is when I use the `curl_setopt($cs, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);`

I will not work :/
but if I comment it out it works just fine..

Can anyone see what I have done wrong?

Many thanks!

Comment: Is there any error in your `errors.log` file? Is your proxy written correctly (`xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:pppp` format)? Is `curl_error($ch)` containing something that can help?

Comment: Maybe you also need to set CURLOPT_PROXYAUTH

Comment: @Ninsuo Nothing in the errors.log And the proxy is in the correct format :)
how does this `curl_error($ch)` ?

@HankyPanky And I have checked no need for `CURLOPT_PROXYAUTH`

Comment: do a simple `echo curl_error($ch);` [see manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php) for details.

Comment: @Ninsuo I get this:

`Notice: Undefined variable: cs in C:\xampp\htdocs\traffic\updown.php on line 75`

`Warning: curl_error() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\traffic\updown.php on line 75`
It's where I added `echo curl_error($ch);`

Comment: Do it just before your `curl_close`

Comment: Okay I get this message: `couldn't connect to host`
Uhm.. but the host is google :/